# How to add 1000 nodes of the same content type in just one step?

Tags: 7, nodes

I need some advice with the following situation:

I have a content type called: "Flats".

I have to add 1000 nodes for this content type.

The only field I need to complete for all of them is the 'title'

I have the 1000 titles in a comma-separated-value format file called: **title.csv**

Is there any way to upload this file and add all the nodes in just one step.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Drupal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) will also allow you to import content/create nodes via CSV.

Comment: It looks fine. I'll try it.

Comment: Just a question: what is GUID field?

Comment: Feeds can use this ID as an externally supplied unique ID that it recognizes so that it can updated the nodes it creates based on this ID.

Comment: ok, then it could be arbitrary? Let's say 'my guid' or '1234'

Comment: yes is is arbitrary, as long as it is unique to that 'flat'. If you will never need to re-import that 1,000 nodes again, it is optional.

Answer (score 5):

If it's sample data, you can use the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). If you want to import data that is in some file or db you can use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6). If the data is exported from another Drupal installation, you can use the [Node Import module](http://drupal.org/project/node_import).

Comment: I need to importa node from csv file. The right module is **Feeds module** but its documentations is really poor. Found a screencast but for d6.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) that supports CSV files

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is for drupal 7. Node import is not available for d7